# Как сделать запрет на создание больше 1 фрейма?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Подскажите, пожалуйста, *каким образом можно запретить кнопке создавать фрейм, если в данный момент он (фрейм) уже открыт?* Если это не возможно сделать, то *можно ли как-то изменить действие, происходящее при нажатии кнопки закрытия фрейма (эта та, которая обычно устанавливается как JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation() )?*

**Код:**

```
    class Creater implements ActionListener {

    JButton create;
    String s;
    JTextField listN;
    JFrame fC;
    JPanel p;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (lists.size() < 50) {
                create = new JButton("Создать");
                s = Integer.toString(i);
                fC = new JFrame();
                fC.setVisible(true);
                fC.setSize(230, 105);
                fC.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
                fC.setTitle("Создать лист");
                fC.setResizable(false);
                JLabel labelN = new JLabel(" Имя листа:");
                fC.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, labelN);
                listN = new JTextField("Лист " + s);
                listN.setBorder(null);
                fC.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, listN);
                listN.moveCaretPosition(listN.getText().length());
                p = new JPanel();
                fC.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, p);
                p.add(create);
                create.addActionListener(new C());
                p.add(out(c, fC));
            } else {
                fC = new JFrame();
                fC.setVisible(true);
                fC.setSize(260, 100);
                fC.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
                fC.setTitle("Создать лист");
                fC.setResizable(false);
                JLabel labelN = new JLabel(" Количество листов превышает максимум. ");
                fC.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, labelN);
                p.remove(create);
                fC.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, p);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите [ссылку 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951123/button-opens-new-jframe-multiple-times-how-do-i-stop-this) и [ссылку 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755736/allow-only-1-child-jframe-on-the-screen).

UPD
Вот код под твое ТЗ)
Первый класс 
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class hashcodejframe extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("Parent");
    JButton btnShowDaughterFrame = new JButton();

    DaughterFrame dFrame = null;
    DaughterFrame dFrameTempRef = null;
    hashcodejframe mainFrame = null;

    public hashcodejframe()
    {
        super("Main frame");

        btnShowDaughterFrame.setText("Invoke");
        btnShowDaughterFrame.setSize(40, 30);
        this.add(btnShowDaughterFrame, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent mwe)
            {
                if(dFrame != null)
                {
                    dFrame.dispose();
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        setSize(300, 400);

        btnShowDaughterFrame.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new hashcodejframe();

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dFrameTempRef = DaughterFrame.showDFrame();

        if(dFrameTempRef != null)
        {
            dFrame = dFrameTempRef;
        }

        dFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
            {
                DaughterFrame.decRef();
                dFrame.dispose();
            }
        });

    }



}
```

Вот второй класс
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DaughterFrame extends JFrame {
    JLabel labelDaughter = new JLabel("Daughter");

```
private static DaughterFrame dInstance = null;

public DaughterFrame() {
    super();
    add(labelDaughter);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(200, 200);
}

public static DaughterFrame showDFrame()
{
    if(dInstance == null)
    {
        dInstance = new DaughterFrame();
        return dInstance;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void decRef()
{
    if(dInstance != null)
    {
        dInstance = null;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то советуют либо null присваивать, либо dispose. Проблема в том, что если делать через null, то при клике пользователем на кнопку закрытия фрейма(крестик то есть) нельзя назначить fC=null. А вот как с dispose, я, честно говоря, не понял, пробовал fC.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) - не помогает. Может кодом поможете?

Comment: Наверх глянь.